# How to stop the setTimeout or setInterval inside loop?

Tags: javascript, animation, settimeout, setinterval, cleartimeout

I'd gone through a plenty of posts in SO with the similar queries but unfortunately none of them fit into my requirements or solved my problem.

The problem is When I click play button, I want to go through all the iteration(102) of while with certain delay(for visualisation purpose) until I click the pause button.  If the pause button is clicked at iteration 73 execution, I want to stop at the current iteration(73) and save this step. Later, If the play button is pressed, I want to resume from the iteration(73/74) from where I left off. Variable curStp is used to monitor the current steps.

Currently, when the pause button is pressed, the loop is not stopping and it keeps going till it reaches 102.

```js
let flag = 0;
const delay = 300;
const totalStps = 102;
var curStp = 0;

function mouseup() {
  let i = 0;
  console.log("Value of flag " + flag);
  while(i < totalStps - curStp) {
    const j = i;
    var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       let stp = curStp;
       console.log("i " + i + "  j " + j + " curStp " + curStp);
       
       curStp = stp+1;   // this is done by setState.
       console.log("flag " + flag + " timeout " + timeout);
        }, delay * i);
        
    if (flag === 1) {
       console.log("break the loop");
       clearTimeout(timeout);
       // This is not stopping this setTimeout
       break;
    }
    i++;
  } 
}

function pause() {
  flag = 1;
  console.log("Value of flag in pause()  " + flag + " curStp " + curStp);
  let stp = curStp;
  curStp = stp;   // this is done by setState.
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mouseup()">Run Code
</button>
<button onclick="pause()">Pause Code
</button>
```

I tried the same with setInterval also but no luck. It also runs in a jiffy and hurting my eyes.

```js
let flag = 0;
const delay = 300;
const totalStps = 102;
var curStp = 0;

function mouseup() {
  let i = 0;
  console.log("Value of flag " + flag);
  while(i < totalStps - curStp) {
    const j = i;
    (function(i) {
    var timeout = setInterval(function(){
       let stp = curStp;
       console.log("i " + i + "  j " + j + " curStp " + curStp);
       
       curStp = stp+1;   // this is done by setState.
       console.log("flag " + flag + " timeout " + timeout);
        }, delay * i)
    })(i);
    if (flag === 1) {
       console.log("break the loop");
       clearInterval(timeout);
       // This is not stopping this setTimeout
       break;
    }
    i++;
  } 
}

function pause() {
  flag = 1;
  console.log("Value of flag in pause()  " + flag + " curStp " + curStp);
  let stp = curStp;
  curStp = stp;   // this is done by setState.
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mouseup()">Run Code
</button>
<button onclick="pause()">Pause Code
</button>
```

Am I missing any thing?

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` return an id that you can then use to stop with `clearTimeout` or `clearInterval`. Note this ONLY works before the it's actually executed.

Comment: Either create a loop with `setTimeout` or create `setInterval` without loop around it. Now you are creating a new interval ticker at **every** iteration of the loop.

Comment: `setTimeout()` is asynchronous -- it starts the timer, but doesn't wait for it to finish. So the `if (flag == 1)` executes immediately, it will never see the changes made by the `pause()` function. You can't use a loop to wait for an async change.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the reply. I couldn't understand the last line. What is async change here? I could understand that setTimeout is asynchronous that it completes the work at its own self-paced schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you do it this way:

1. Don't use a while loop because the while loop will call setTimeout many times and then you will have to clear ALL of them to pause. So it is simpler to not use the while loop
2. When the function is called, let it set a timeout again after it is run.
3. This means when `toRepeat` in my example below runs, it will create a timeout to run again so it runs the next step. Then it runs again and calls `setTimeout` again and so on until `curStp` is less than `totalStps`

Here is an example with comments, let me know if anything needs clarification.

```
let flag = 0;
const delay = 300;
const totalStps = 102;
var curStp = 0;
var timeout = null;

function toRepeat() {
    let stp = curStp;
    console.log("curStp = " + curStp);
    
    curStp = stp+1;   // this is done by setState.
    console.log("flag " + flag + " timeout " + timeout);

    // check for pause
    if(flag === 1) {
      console.log("break the loop");
      console.log('clearing timeout = ', timeout);

      // dont continue because we paused
      return;
    }

    // each timeout will call another timeout again for the next step unless we already finished or we have paused
    // better to have this `curStp < totalStps`
    if(curStp != totalStps) {
      // setup another timeout for next step
      timeout = setTimeout(toRepeat, delay);
    } else {
      // we already finished
    }
}

function mouseup() {
  // need to set the flag back to 0 so pressing "Run Code" doesn't immediately pause again
  flag = 0;

  var timeout = setTimeout(toRepeat, delay);
}

function pause() {
  flag = 1;
  console.log("Value of flag in pause()  " + flag + " curStp " + curStp);
  let stp = curStp;
  curStp = stp;   // this is done by setState.
}
```

Comment: This worked!! I'm really thankful as I was struggling for a day. I'm just a week old to Javascript (Laughs). So, Isn't the loop needed if the setTimeout is chosen? I hope it's better if we go with recursion instead of loop for setTimeout.

Comment: Shouldn't we clear the timeout when the flag is 1 in toRepeat() ?

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript :) We don't need to clear the timeout in `toRepeat` function because when we are inside the `toRepeat` function the timeout already finished executing. Actually we don't need to the `timeout` variable at all in the example

Comment: Yes, I agree. We don't need the timeout variable at all. Also, we don't want to clearTimeout. The one is dependant on another and we don't need neither of them in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `while` loop when you use `setInterval`. The latter already has an (asynchronous) repeat logic!

Here is what I think you only need:

- `timeout` should be a variable that has large enough scope to perform `clearInterval` on it
- `flag` is not needed. Just reset `timeout` to `undefined`
- No `i` or `j` are needed
- No repeated calls of `setInterval` and no `delay * i` either. Those are ingredients you would sometimes use for `setTimeout`, but not `setInterval`

```js
const delay = 300;
const totalStps = 102;

let curStp = 0;
let timeout;

function mouseup() {
  if (timeout !== undefined) return; // Don't start when already started
  // No loop here!
  timeout = setInterval(function() {
    curStp++;
    console.log("Current step " + curStp);
    if (curStp >= totalStps) {
      console.log("Finished at " + curStp);
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = undefined;
      curStp = 0;
    }
  }, delay);
}

function pause() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = undefined;
  console.log("Paused at " + curStp);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mouseup()">Run Code</button>
<button onclick="pause()">Pause Code</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can come up with

```js
const delay = 200;
const totalStps = 102;
var curStp = 0;
var interval

function mouseup() {
  if(!interval){
    interval = setInterval(()=>{
      if(curStp == totalStps){
        pause()
      } else {
        curStp = curStp +1
        console.log(curStp)
      }
    }, delay)
  }
}

function pause() { 
  clearInterval(interval)
  interval = undefined
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mouseup()">Run Code</button>
<button onclick="pause()">Pause Code</button>
```